# Spring boot hibernate giving exception when fetching roles set from user entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am having problems fetching the result set with roles from a user entity from database throw hibernate this is what I have this far:
Here is the database
[my sql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFtsO.png)

And this is the exception i am geting

> ## Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Sat Jan 19 18:37:17 CET 2019There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).Could not write JSON: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.springboot.model.User["roles"])

And these are my java beans: User entity

```
package com.example.springboot.model;



import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="userid")
private int id;

@Column(name="username")
private String username;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@Column(name="email")
private String email;

@Column(name="password")
private String password;

@Column(name="datecreated")
private String dateCreated;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userid"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleid"))
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
}

public void setDateCreated(String dateCreated) {
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
}

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Userid: "+id;
}
}
```

And role entity

```
package com.example.springboot.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="role")
public class Role {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="role")
private String role;

@Column(name="description")
private String description;
}
```

Please help me I am trying to fix this all day but no hope.

- 2019-01-19 18:28:05.321  INFO 9968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
- 2019-01-19 18:28:05.499  WARN 9968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
- 2019-01-19 18:28:05.499 ERROR 9968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'role1_.id' in 'field list'
- 2019-01-19 18:28:05.501  WARN 9968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.springboot.model.User["roles"])]
- 2019-01-19 18:28:08.440  WARN 9968 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
- 2019-01-19 18:28:08.440 ERROR 9968 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'role1_.id' in 'field list'
- 2019-01-19 18:28:08.440  WARN 9968 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: com.example.springboot.model.User["roles"])]
- 2019-01-19 18:37:17.963  WARN 9968 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
- 2019-01-19 18:37:17.963 ERROR 9968 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'role1_.id' in 'field list'
- 2019-01-19 18:37:17.963  WARN 9968 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.springboot.model.User["roles"])]

Comment: In the logs it's mentioned that unknown column "role1_.id", please provide your schema details and what you are trying i.e getRoles or getRole ?

Comment: The schema is the same as in the picture at the second row I have no role1_.id.I have the many to many user_role talbe and user and role tables respectively.I am trying to get all users with:                                              
public List<User> getUsers(){
        return (List<User>) userRepository.findAll();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [your schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFtsO.png), (in Role class) it should be:

```
@Column(name="roleid")
```

..instead of:

```
@Column(name="id")
```